# sql query to retrieve three records

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, apache-flex, actionscript

1 - I wanted to know SQL query that will retrieve three records who's id I will provide.
I,m using Sqlite db in a Flex Mobile Project.

2 - I also wanted to know SQL query for getting records b/w 2 given dates.
I,m using Sqlite db in a flex mobile project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id IN (..,..,etc.);
```

2.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE date BETWEEN date1 AND date2;
```